# suddenly i am getting Invalid Firebase Database path: driver@driver.com Firebase Database paths must not contain '.','#','$' etc

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pickup, PID: 5026
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: driver@driver.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validatePathString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:45)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:102)
    at com.example.pickup.DriverMapActivity.getAssignedCustomerPickupLocation(DriverMapActivity.java:146)
    at com.example.pickup.DriverMapActivity.access$200(DriverMapActivity.java:46)
    at com.example.pickup.DriverMapActivity$3.onDataChange(DriverMapActivity.java:130)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5026 SIG: 9

These are the errors I get. This happens when I try to login. the details is appearing in the authentication and realtime database. but my app crashes

```
private void getAssignedCustomerPickupLocation(){
    DatabaseReference assignedCustomerPickupLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("customerRequest").child(CustomerId).child("l");
    assignedCustomerPickupLocationRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                List<Object> map = (List<Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                double locationLat = 0;
                double locationLng = 0;
                if(map.get(0) != null){
                    locationLat = Double.parseDouble(map.get(0).toString());
                }
                if(map.get(1) != null){
                    locationLng = Double.parseDouble(map.get(1).toString());
                }
                LatLng driverLatLang = new LatLng(locationLat,locationLng);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLatLang).title("pickup location"));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please help it is really urgent

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't operation on any sense of urgency.  Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  Be clear about how you are building the path to the node with the invalid character.

Comment: I am working on an uberlike app, and I dint have any issues, dont know what triggered it.

Comment: Without seeing source code, there's nothing we can do to help.  The code is building a path to a node using an invalid character.  You will have to debug it.

Comment: I have uploaded the code

Comment: the error is showing at the second line

Answer (score 0):

The value of `CustomerId` contains one of the characters in the list of invalid characters in the error message.  You will have to debug your app in order to figure out where that value comes from, and check that it's valid before calling Realtime Database with it.

Comment: Thankyou Stevenson, You are a lifesaver. in 5hors i had to submit my project in my college, And I thought I was done for good.